# Create GitHub.com Hook

Tags: github, github-api, github-services

I am attempting to create a hook using the create hook api found on

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#create-a-hook

but I am getting a 301 when I attempt to post, so I am sure I am doing it wrong...

A couple of questions...

1) How does github know that I can create a hook for that repo if it is private? I am sure I need to authenticate with the POST, but how?

2) Is the following curl statement a valid example of how to create a hook?

```
 curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{ "name": "cia", 
 "active": true, "events": [ "push" ], "config": { 
 "url": "http://requestb.in/######", "content_type": "json" } }"
  http://github.com/repos/#####/#####/hooks
```

I have replaced certain elements with ##### for security sake...

3) If the above is incorrect, may I please have a snippet of a valid example to create a hook for the webhook named "cia"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
curl -usigmavirus24 -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name": "cia", "active": true, "events": ["push"], "config": {"url": "...", "content_type": "json"}}' https://api.github.com/repos/sigmavirus24/reponame/hooks
```

Is the correct curl command. The URL you're posting to has to be `https://api.github.com/:endpoint` where `:endpoint` in this case is `repos/username/reponame/hooks`. You also need to use `'`s around the JSON body for the curl command because otherwise you'll get strings like `"{ "` concatenated with the output of commands like `name`, `cia`, `active`, `events`, etc.

Also the `-u :username` option is necessary for curl so it will tell curl that it MUST authenticate and ask you for the password to do so.

If you don't mind your password being in your bash history (WHICH YOU SHOULD) you can also do `-u username:password`. Or even better you can base64 encode your credentials in the form `username:password` and then send that as a header like so: `Authentication: Basic <base64-encoded-credentials`.

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts It's a pleasure to help. You should also check out the [libraries](http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/) already available for interacting with the API.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 : Do you have the updated link of those libraries ?

Comment: Some rudimentary looking around at developer.github.com would have brought you to https://developer.github.com/libraries/